# C Pointer Arithmetic Problems

Tags: c, math, pointers

I'm having a little fiddle with pointer arithmetic and just pointer in general and I've pulled together this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    void *ptr=NULL;
    char a='a';
    int i0=0;
    char b='b';
    int i1=1;
    char c='c';
    int i2=2;
    ptr=&a;
    //What do I do here to get to i0?
    printf("%d",(int*)ptr); //and to print it out?
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is exactly what I put into the comments. How do I get ptr to point to i0 without doing 'ptr=&i0;' using pointer arithmetic? Also how do I then print it out correctly for characters and integers(one method for char and one for int).

Thanks in advance. ;)

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title of your question. Stack Overflow does not work like a traditional forum. All you need to do to indicate that your issue is solved is accept the answer that helped you to solve the issue. I see that you've already done that here, so thanks!

Comment: @Cody Gray Thank you for telling me that. I personally just find that if I'm looking for questions to answer, '[SOLVED]' stands out to me so that I don't even have to read the actual question it's self. Saves more time for the people who go around answering questions(of which I do not). ;)

Comment: Well, questions with accepted answers are shown a little bit differently in the list, too. Questions with an answer have a green background, and if the answer has been accepted, the text in the green background is yellow. You should see it on the homepage and in the [Question list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions). :-) But I like to browse questions even with accepted answers, because I might learn something new myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only thing I can think of is:

```
ptr += ((char*)&i0 - &a)
```

but not sure if it's valid anyway and it doesn't make much difference from `ptr = &i0`

as others pointed out, in accordance to the standard you can only do pointer arithmetic within bounds of a single object, like a struct or array, so the code above even if it might work is not really correct

Comment: Thanks. Yours worked perfectly! I just realised that pointer arithmetic was more designed more arrays but yours made me realise. I was adding things like 'sizeof(int)' and whatnot when really I should have been adding addresses. ;)

Comment: actually you can't add addresses ;) you rather add addresses' differences or simply call it offsets, this will work for two fields in a struct, but for automatic variables on the stack, as well global variables it is unfortunately undefined

Comment: @MarcAlexanderReed  Just keep in mind it might not work tomorrow. Or it might break if you enable optimization, or update the compiler.

Comment: @nos How would I access b then? I'm trying this piece of code but it just causes a crash: "ptr+=(&b-&a); printf("%s",****(char****)ptr);" And would you class this part of CS as Address/Memory Arithmetic?

Comment: @MarcAlexanderReed As others have said, you cannot really do this in C, not in any reliable and well defined way. If you want to access b, use b. If you want to do pointer arithmetic, do pointer arithmetic within an array, not on different local variables. imo. this has little to do with CS , and everything to do with how the C programming language is defined.

Answer (score 7):

The *only* way to get a pointer to the location of `i0` is `& i0`.

While some compilers may align `i0` so that `* ((int*) (((char*) ptr) - 1))` can be used to access `i0`, that's not guaranteed. Compilers often reorder local variables or may not even store them in memory at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get `ptr` to point to `i0` using pointer arithmetic. Pointer arithmetic only works within the bounds of a single array object (non-array variables are treated as arrays of size 1). You can't use pointer arithmetic to make a pointer skip from one standalone object to another.

Comment: +1: but `x = malloc(42 * sizeof *x);` does not create an array and you can ( *make a copy first* ) do pointer arithmetic with `x` ;)

Comment: @pmg: In C `malloc` is considered to be capable of *creating an object* of any type, assuming the pointer is suitably assigned and the size is sufficient. This is conveyed through the concepts of *declared type* and *effective type* in C99.

Comment: Hmmm ... it makes sense to consider the storage allocated by `malloc` as an object of array type. I have been considering that storage basically as *untyped object*. Thank you.

Comment: @pmg: Well, AFAIK, this was indeed an underdeveloped area in C89/90. It was described more formally in C99.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense.  You have no guarantee of where a, i0, b, i1, c and i2 are defined in memory when they're created - so you can't use pointer arithmetic to move from the address of a (ptr=&a) to i0.

If you want ptr to equal i0's location you can do ptr = &i0.  If i0 was an integer (which it is) it will be 4 bytes big, so you can use pointer arithmetic to move through that integer 1 btye at a time if your pointer is void/char.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this.

Pointer arithmetic works on pointer to array elements that is, you can do arithmetic on a pointer that points to an element within an array to adjust the pointer to another element within that same array.

You cannot do pointer arithmetic on a pointer to a variable and make it point to another unrelated variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can only do pointer arithmetic within a whole object (like an array). This works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int arr[100];
    int *ptr;
    arr[42] = 42;
    ptr = arr; /* ptr points to the 1st element */
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr + 42)); /* contents of the 43rd element */
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code sample, without doing

```
ptr=&i0;
```

You cannot get `ptr` to point to `i0` **portably** because,
`i0` is just a local variable & it's address is not stored in any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    union u
    {
       char ch;
       int i;
    } arr[] = { { .ch = 'a' }, { .i = 0 }, { .ch = 'b' }, { .i = 1 } };

    union u *ptr = &arr[0];
    printf("%d\n", ptr[1].i);
}
```

Not exactly what you wrote but would work.